# How to replace slashes with line breaks from a string

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to know how to replaces all slashes of a string with line break using ColdFusion.

**Example**:
Director/Manager

**should be**:
Director
Manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cfset result = replaceNoCase("Director/Manager","/",chr(13)&chr(10),"all")>
```

Comment: Hi William,
Thanks for your reply. It works fine. What does chr(13)&chr(10) exactyl mean?

Comment: It is ASCII for a line break and a carriage return